# How to pass document referrer in overlay object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We are using a html embedded object as given below. We are trying to find the referrer on server side from the request. But in Safari browser referrer is not setting. Is there a way we can pass referrer explicitly in this scenario?

```
<object id=\"\" codebase=\"http://www.sample.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab#version=7,3,0,0\" width=\"848\" height=\"480\" classid=\"clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B\" class=\" quicktime\"><param value=\""+videoURL+"\" name=\"src\"><param value=\"transparent\" name=\"wmode\"><param value=\"false\" name=\"showlogo\"><param value=\"tofit\" name=\"scale\"><param value=\"true\" name=\"saveembedtags\"><param value=\"true\" name=\"postdomevents\"><embed src=\""+videoURL+"\" type=\"video/quicktime\" wmode=\"transparent\" postdomevents=\"true\" controller=\"true\" showlogo=\"false\" scale=\"tofit\" width=\"848\" height=\"480\" airplay=\"allow\" posterframe=\"http://sample.com/global/elements/quicktime/qt_endstate848x480.jpg\" autostart=\"true\" cache=\"true\" bgcolor=\"white\" aggressivecleanup=\"false\" style=\"width: 848px; height: 480px; \"><param value=\"true\" name=\"controller\"><param value=\"http://sample.com/global/elements/quicktime/qt_endstate848x480.jpg\" name=\"posterframe\"><param value=\"false\" name=\"showlogo\"><param value=\"true\" name=\"autostart\"><param value=\"true\" name=\"cache\"><param value=\"white\" name=\"bgcolor\"><param value=\"false\" name=\"aggressivecleanup\"></object>
```

Comment: For the same code in Firefox we are getting referrer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the referrer in Javascript using `document.referrer`, though my understanding is that it would be a mistake to rely on it. I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, though - this would give you the *previous* page the user was on, whereas when the server receives the request for the video I assume you want the *current* page, which is available as `location.href`. You could add this as a querystring parameter to the video URL to pass it to the server.

But I'm guessing that you're trying to restrict the content of the video to only be shown on a particular site. In this case, passing the referrer explicitly through a querystring is going to be insufficient, because it's too easy to spoof. In that case, you might be better off using some sort of token-based verification. You might be able to use [this technique for avoiding cross-site request forgeries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works), which relies on checking a site-specific cookie against a parameter that's passed to the server.